# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage with PropertyChanged.Fody not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I am using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio. Now I have the problem that ImplementPropertyChanged (Nuget: PropertyChanged.Fody) is not working correctly. Is there a known problem with this Nuget and the MasterDetailPage?

I use the MVVM pattern and have a BaseViewModel that implements PropertyChanged.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Every ViewModel is like this

```
public class MyViewModel() : BaseViewModel
{
}
```

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `BaseViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. My BaseViewModel ist now using : INotifyPropertyChanged instead of the nuget. Worked for me.